# Identify Value Textbox with Value Column Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

maybe this is an easy question. but not for me
What do I have?
I have a Worksheet (named ZTN) with 5 Columns
Under A there are 2 values "Yes or No" / Column B CHNumber (for example CH4711) / Column C Items for exampl "Salt" Column D is free (no values) and E ZTN with numeric values (ZTN Number)

I also have a User Form with 3 Textboxes Txtbx44 for the Items Textbox 46 for the ZTN Number and a Txtbx named MatNr

I also have a command Button Search

What have I done?

When I manualy fill in the Textbox "Ware" and trigger the search button my macro find the values in Sheet "ZTN" an fill the Txtbxes MatNr and ZTN
Here my Code

```
Dim raFund As Range

Set raFund = Worksheets("ZTN").Columns("C").Find(what:=UserForm1.Ware, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not raFund Is Nothing Then                    
           TextBox46 = Worksheets("ZTN").Cells(raFund.Row, "E")
           MatNr = Worksheets("ZTN").Cells(raFund.Row, "B")
              
           If Worksheets("ZTN").Cells(raFund.Row, "E") = Worksheets("ZTN").Cells(raFund.Row, "A").Value = "JA" Then
                MsgBox "T1 RELEVANT!"
           End If
    Else
           If MsgBox("Ware ist nicht vorhanden, soll ein neuer Eintrag angelegt werden?", vbYesNo, "Neuer Eintrag") = vbYes Then
             With Worksheets("ZTN")
                loLetzte = .Columns(2).Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1).Row
                .Cells(loLetzte, "A") = Me.MatNr
                .Cells(loLetzte, "B") = Me.Ware
              ' .Cells(loLetzte, "D") = Me.Zolltarifnummer
             End With
           End If
    End If
Set raFund = Nothing

End Sub
```

What do I want to to?
I try to identify if the found ZTN NUmber is a T1 case or not for a further different workflow. (thats why I I have Column A in Worksheet "ZTN" with the Value "Yes" or "No" regadring the ZTN Number.

By now I stuck cause equal what item I´m typing in ... the Msgbox says "T1 Relevant!"

I also stuck with the Items
By now when I try to find Salt it will find Salt. But there are diffrent kinds of Salt in my List
(another example
UCC0.1 / UTN0.2 / BTS0:0; Reinigungs-und Ätzmischungen für Mikroelektronikanwendungen

That means the Item UCC.1 means UTN0.2 means... Reinigungs-...)

It would be nice to find the Item similiar to the search function in Excel itsself.
Not regarding the upper and lower case

I hope sombody will have a good idea

Thx in advance
Pete

Comment: `If Worksheets("ZTN").Cells(raFund.Row, "E") = Worksheets("ZTN").Cells(raFund.Row, "A").Value = "JA" Then`  what are you testing here?

Comment: Hi Timethx for your help

Comment: HI Tim in a first step I want to fill the textboxes.. means  Mat Nr and ZTN Number.. that works fine. In a second step I wanted to check if the ZTN Number is T1 Relevant or not. Thats what I intetnded with Worksheet "ZTN" and Column A filled with the Value Yes or No regarding if the ZTN Nnumber is T1 Relevant (YES) or not (NO)